# Do sports compression clothes give their claimed benefits?

Tags: medical-science, consumer-products, sport

Sellers of sports compression clothes make a lot of claims about their products.

Here are some I saw on the back of a 2XU packet. This is not exclusive to them:

> Benefits of compression
>
> - Greater oxygenation of blood for faster recovery
> - Faster muscle warm up pre-exercise
> - Reduced fatigue through less muscle oscillation
> - Reduced muscle soreness
> - Reduced long-term overuse injuries Reduced power output
> - Heightened proprioception - awareness of limb placement or agility

There are a lot of claims on their [website](https://www.2xu.com/au/compression.html), so what are and are not backed up? Under Armour and Skins seem to make similar claims.

Note if this should be multiple questions, I'm happy to break it up further.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to question the general claim of benefits to wearing the equipment, and itemising specific claims to be evaluated means they can each be dissected in context of the others. Keep the lot together (support for single question, not splitting).

Comment: http://www.runnersworld.com/rt-web-exclusive/compression-gear-hype-of-helpful